# can i force heroku to run my app on http instead of https ? nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

hey I was wondering if I can force start my heroku app on http instead of https
I know it might be not secure but it's for a school project

I am using nodejs and express

Answer (score 0):

heroku allows you to run on `https` when you use there domain they give you

```
testapp.herokuapp.com
```

if you want to connect your domain, you can do so, but it is best to purchase it their $7 a month fee for ssl cert. since you mentioned this is a school project, I would suggest just using their domain they give to you, that would be best.

also, that's awesome you get to build node app for school project! If you need any help, let me know

Comment: i do need tons of help i am not going to lie 
is there any way i can contact you ?

Comment: sorry if that was asking too much @Gianluca

Comment: email me at gianluca@piersolutions.ca and I can try to help